# How to use Python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

The scenario is: I am  on Ubuntu 11 which comes with Python 2.7, I want to run Mozilla JetPack which supports Python 2.5/2.6 and Google App Engine which only supports Python 2.5.

Read that its not a good idea to remove Python 2.7 as Ubuntu maybe using it. So the correct way is to use `virtualenv`. But I am quite lost using it. I installed Python 2.5 in `/usr/local/python25` following **[this guide](http://welcometoubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/05/howto-install-python-255-on-ubuntu-1004.html)**

I tried

```
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ ./python --version
Python 2.5.5
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ ./python virtualenv /works/tmp/test
./python: can't open file 'virtualenv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

then the below works but I will be using Python 2.7

```
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ virtualenv /works/tmp/test
New python executable in /works/tmp/test/bin/python
Installing distribute.................................................................................................................................................................................done.
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ cd /works/tmp/test/bin
jiewmeng@JM:/works/tmp/test/bin$ ls
activate  activate_this.py  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  python
jiewmeng@JM:/works/tmp/test/bin$ ./python --version
Python 2.7.1+
```

Also, how do I then run Mozilla JetPack or Google App Engine with this version of Python? Sorry I am new to Python (and Linux/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Outline:**

- First cd to `/usr/local/python25/bin`
- Download setuptools for Python2.5 ([setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg#md5=64c94f3bf7a72a13ec83e0b24f2749b2))
- Install it (`sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg`).
- Now install pip (`easy_install pip`).
- Install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` using pip (`pip install v...` etc.).
- Configure WORKON_HOME for virtualenv wrapper to work (`export WORKON_HOME = $HOME/.virtualenvs`). You can use any other directory you want (not just $HOME/.virtualenvs). Just make sure to use the full path.
- Now create a virtualenv (`mkvirtualenv foobar`).
- Switch to the new virtualenv (`workon foobar`).
- Now install GAE, JetPack and whatever you want using `pip install blah`

**Why did your install not work?**

Looks like you did not install virtualenv for Python2.5. Hence this will not work.

```
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ ./python virtualenv /works/tmp/test
```

You can check by running `ls` command in that directory. I suspect you won't find `virtualenv` file there.

However this worked for you.

```
jiewmeng@JM:/usr/local/python25/bin$ virtualenv /works/tmp/test
```

Because it is using the `virtualenv` file for system default Python2.7. You can check `which virtualenv` and opening the `virtualenv` script. You'll see that the #! will point to system default python.

So you need to install the easy_install and pip for Python 2.5 before you can create virtualenv for Python 2.5. Just follow the steps outlined above.

Comment: did I just install setup tools to python 2.7? how can I install it for Python 2.5. Also do I need to reverse the changes or correct it? http://pastie.org/1826922

Comment: @jiewmeng Here are the first couple of lines from setuptools for 2.5 egg. 

#!/bin/sh
if [ `basename $0` = "setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg" ]
then exec python2.5 -c 
....

As you can see, it tries to python2.5 binary to install setuptools which should install to Python 2.5 folder. I suspect python 2.5 was not installed properly. Try typing python2.5 in bash and see if python 2.5 terminal opens. If it does not, then you'll need to install Python 2.5 and then run setuptools installation again.

Comment: whats the problem ... I tried to create a symlink but I get 2.7.1+ ... http://pastie.org/1827650. How do u install different versions of Python? I used **[this guide](http://welcometoubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/05/howto-install-python-255-on-ubuntu-1004.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything fancy outside the virtualenv wrapper.  Just use the `--python=python2.5` flag (check out the man page for virtualenv form more). It does not matter what version you install it with, you just have to select the right executable for python in the virtual environment.

e.g. `mkvirtualenv --python=python2.5 --distribute python25`  if the python flag fails, either add a symlink (`ln -s`) to python25 in your $PATH or use the full path name on the python flag.

Also, default for multiple python installations is to have, for all 'altinstall' versions, a separate python and easy_install. So, for example: `python2.5` ,`easy_install-2.5` ,`python2.6`, `easy_install-2.6` etc.