# Install multiple versions of the same package (with same version number) with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

How do I install multiple versions of the same package, with the same package version number, using setuptools? And how would I then import the desired package?

Is it possible to override the version number, i.e. tell setuptools to install Foo-1.1 as Foo-1.1_openmpi instead?

I.e.

- I compile Foo-1.1 using open mpi
- and also Foo-1.1 using a different mpi version
- and again Foo-1.1 using a different QT version

Note, this is not to be confused with installing multiple packages with different version numbers i.e. foo1.1 and foo1.2.

Comment: No, to `easy_install` the egg version number and platform name are the *only* two values that make an egg unique. You cannot override that. Generally speaking, avoid binary eggs and only distribute and install source packages.

Comment: You could try to trick it (by editing the package) into appending extra cruft onto either the name or the version number, but this will confuse setuptools/easy_install/pip later.

Comment: Do you need the multiple versions at the same time?  If not, e.g. you're just testing with various package versions, I'd suggest [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: Also, even if you managed to make this work, you'd end up with two modules or packages at the top level with the exact same name, so `import Foo` would import one of them, and there'd be no way at all to import the other (and I don't think it's even well defined which is which).

Comment: The simplest way to solve this is probably to fork the source and rename both the module and the setuptools package in the variant version. This may require a bit of manual or semi-automated cleanup work, but really, it's the only way you're going to get two working things that you can import separately at the same time.

Comment: @Martijn How do i get around the problem if I install from source? The egg is generated from a larger source build process (visualisation toolkit vtk) as at some stage it calls 'python setup.py install'. My usual process was to just link the package into site-packages and rename to what I want. My same approach doesnt appear to work for python eggs.

Comment: Ah okay, this is what I had feared. 

It is for testing, I will try virtualenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you actually need to use different versions of the same package simultaneously (why?!), I would suggest using a Python Virtual Environment via [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

This allows you to easily create isolated virtual environments to run Python.  Each is very cheap and takes no real time to create.  Within each, you can install (via `pip`/`easy_install` or manually with a `setup.py`) whichever packages you want to test with (what I assume you're trying to do).

#### Related:

- [How to use Python virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764494/how-to-use-python-virtualenv)
- Some blog posts:

  - http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/
  - http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html